# I can choose the new name of my position. What would be a good option?

Tags: title

I work at a multinational company that makes digital games. I joined three months ago, and my position is content trafficking coordinator, also known as "trafficker". But the name of this position is a bit unusual to me. I don't remember seeing anyone in such a role before.

I'm the middle person between two teams in different countries, one that creates our product (HQ) and another that creates promotion and communication for that content in a specific region (which is the country where I'm in).

I'm an enabler, so I'm the one who always need to know what's happening at the HQ to provide my team with what they need to get their work done (audiovisual assets, information, and so on). I also need to let HQ know what we're promoting, why, and how. That means I create a lot short documents that formalize such initiatives. I **rarely create** new initiatives in this position, so it's more of an organizational role of what other people are creating.

Even though what I'm doing is actually managing the flow of information between two teams, which "content trafficking coordinator" describes well, it's a name that might be hard for people in other companies to understand what I do upfront. It's weird having to explain to partners what I do in the company since that name isn't clear enough.

I explained that to my boss and I was told I can choose another name for this role. It's a coordinator position, not management, and the three keywords I cant think of are "production", "content", and "communication". I want something that people will understand right away what I do.

Some ideas I had were "content production coordinator" and "communications coordinator", but I still feel like something's missing.

Any thoughts on what name would be more beneficial, professional, or better as a whole?

Answer (score 4):

**What is the next job you want?**

Choose as your title what you want your next role to be. Do you prefer the communications side or the product side? The main use for an official title on your resume so you can get the next job.